# react native how to dynamically identify which list item is active?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm rendering a list of items using their index and would like to set and retrieve the state of those items individually. For instance, if the specific item I'm rendering is not active, I render the duration text.

My questions is in the following example: how can I evaluate something like `this.state.[index]'started'` where index is actually the index of the flat list and the not the value index in the state object? I need it to be evaluated to `this.state.1started` and `this.state.2started` .... `this.state.nstarted` automatically.

```
 {!this.state.index && (
    <Text style = {styles.timertext}>
         {this.state.duration}:00
      </Text>
  )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing object's property using bracket notation:

```
this.state[`${index + 1}started`]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the string in bracket notation
 eg:

```
    var obj = { '1started': '2:30', '2started': '3:30' }

    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
       console.log(obj[i +'started']) // 2:30 3:30
    }
```

so, you can use `this.state[index + 1 +'started']`